# Is there a pda with maximum 3 state for every CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free

This is the first question I'm asking here 
I'm trying to understand whether we can construct a PDA with a maximum of 3 states for every possible CFL or not? if so how?

Comment: I believe there is a PDA with one step. The PDA essentially simulates a context-free grammar. The exact number of steps depends on your exact PDA model (for example, what is the acceptance criterion, does the stack get initialized, and so on).

Comment: What Yuval says. One state with empty stack acceptance (see wikipedia). Two states with final state acceptance (move to accept at the end). Three states if you are so unfortunate that you are taught using the Sipser book (which needs to put a bottom stack symbol first).